# Left-continuity of probability-generating function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $G(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} p_n z^n$ for $|z| \leq 1$ be a probability-generating function with $G(1) = 1$, $G'(1^{-}) = 1$, and $G''(1^{-}) \in (0,\infty)$. Then we have
$$
\lim_{z \uparrow 1} \frac{1-G'(z)}{1-z} = 
\lim_{z \uparrow 1} \frac{G'(1^{-})-G'(z)}{1-z}.
$$
Now I wonder if this limit is equal to $G''(1^{-})$. Clearly, this is the case if $G'(1^{-}) = G'(1)$. But what happens if $G'(1^{-}) \neq G'(1)$. How is $G''(1^{-})$ defined in this case?

Comment: If $G'(1)$ exists, then $G'(1^-) = G'(1)$. Anyway, $f(a^-)$ is defined as $$\lim_{\substack{x \to a \\ x < a}} f(x)\,.$$

Comment: Hm, I think Abel's theorem tells us that always $G'(1^-) = G'(1)$.

Comment: In the case of a power series with non-negative coefficients, and if you consider only real arguments, it does indeed (interpreting the equality as $+\infty = +\infty$ in case the differentiated series diverges). If you consider complex $z$ it's a question of how to interpret $G'(1)$. But such problems need not concern us here. What you need is $G''(1^-) = \lim_{z \uparrow 1} G''(z)$ and the mean value theorem.